# Scrollable EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-scrollview

I have designed custom EditText that is inside scrollview. If I scroll the content of EditText it works fine. But while editing/entering text,if I press "enter key" continuously for 6 or 7 times, instead of content, the layout scrolls.

code for click and touch listener :

```
this.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                v.setFocusable(true);
                v.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                v.getParent().getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            }
        });

        this.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        ViewParent p = v.getParent().getParent();
                p.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

It works fine for Android 4.2. Problem exist in Android 4.4. Someone guide me.

**EDIT**
It does general work like set background color and styles.

code:

```
    if (this.textBoxObj == null) {
            return;
        }

        Context context = activity.getApplicationContext();

        // Setting frame
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                this.textBoxObj.frame.getFrameRect().getWidth(),
                this.textBoxObj.frame.getFrameRect().getHeight());
        params.leftMargin = this.textBoxObj.frame.getFrameRect().getX();
        params.topMargin = this.textBoxObj.frame.getFrameRect().getY();
        this.setLayoutParams(params);


        this.setFocusable(false);

        this.setText(this.textBoxObj.textContentInfo.text);
        this.setHint(this.textBoxObj.placeHolderTextContentInfo.text);

        if(isViewUpdate == false)
        {
            this.setBackgroundColor(DUIColor.getLifeColor(this.textBoxObj.objectGeneralProperties.bgColor,context));

            try {
                this.setTextColor(DUIColor.getLifeColor(this.textBoxObj.textContentInfo.textProperties.textColor,context));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            this.setTextSize(this.textBoxObj.textContentInfo.textProperties.textFontSize);
            try {
                this.setTypeface(DUIFont.getTextFontType(this.textBoxObj.textContentInfo.textProperties.textFontType,context));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            this.setGravity(new DUIAlignment().getTextAlignment(this.textBoxObj.textContentInfo.textProperties.alignmentId));
            this.setSingleLine(new DUIAlignment().getTextToWrapOrNot((this.textBoxObj.textContentInfo.textProperties.lineBreakeModeId)));

                this.addTextChangedListener(this);
            this.clearFocus();
       }
```

Please someone guide me as how to solve this problem for Android 4.4 and above.

Comment: Can you post source code from your custom edit text?

Comment: Please see my edit part.